# Owc 11 and Microsoft office 365

Tags: excel-2016, office-2016, office-web-components

I am having an unique issue and unable to find any resolution online. My company is using an application which uses Pivot table and chart controls from Microsoft office 2003 web components ( OWC 11 )

It worked fine till we use 32 bit version of Microsoft Excel 2013. Now we are planning to upgrade to Office 2016 and since it's an old component it's having compatibility issues.

I tried to replace code ( replace Pivot Table class and Chart classes ) but there are no classes for pivot and charts.

```
PivotTableClass objPT = new PivotTableClass();         
objPT.ConnectionString = connString;
objPT.DataMember = "DataMemberString";
```

I am not sure how to replace classes from OWC 11 to make it work with MS Office 2016.

Can anyone plz help?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: use 32 bit version of Excel from Office 2016

Comment: Good to know.. now if I could just remember why I was looking at this :)